# Switch words by index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Seems easy but i failed to find a working example. Basically i need to exchange positions of words in a sentence like...

```
var words='Dennisrec, Jameswoods, Trojanhorse and Superuser like this post';
//now to exchange the position of "Dennisrec" and "Superuser" is a real problem..
```

I have already tried...

```
var words='Dennisrec, Jameswoods, Trojanhorse and Superuser like this post'.match(/\S+[a-z]/g);
```

But this returns an array of all words which also  destroys the string structure but to be frank,
Is there a jquery or javascript function that can get this job done without hussling to much..?

As u can see i have no idea about making this work but its perfectly explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String#replace` with a regular expression and a mapping function. (Note that `\b` represents a zero-length word boundary.)

```js
var words = 'Dennisrec, Jameswoods, Trojanhorse and Superuser like this post'

words = words.replace(/\b(?:Dennisrec|Superuser)\b/g, function (e) {
    return e === 'Dennisrec' ? 'Superuser' : 'Dennisrec'
})

console.log(words)
```

Comment: No problem. Do you need a generic function that can switch any two words?

Comment: No can do, but you really saved me much time. And now I can structure a function which can accomplish more tasks using that code.